# How to delete database value?

Tags: android, database

I have a contacts registering(is simply just to test) but the editText when it is blank it still send the value to the database so, how do I delete it and make an if/else statement for that? i tried

```
           if(myVariable == null){
                   code...
              }....
```

but it havent worked, well the "null" is meant if blank but i dont know it much because im new to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are trying to ensure that your EditText is not empty when you send its value to a database?

```
EditText text = ...

if(text.getText.toString().length() != 0){

  ...database code

}
```

Comment: aaaaahm, so well it must work but the database code i think i not need the "code" maybe just a error dialog well, thanks i will try

Comment: right lets say it might worked but i have 2 EditText lets say: i have "nome" and "telefone" so, how do i put both of them inside the if() ?

Comment: You can use the logical && or logical || operators. The first says if x and y, the second says if x or y.

Comment: ok i will have a try and then edit the comment.  EDIT, yes :d thanks it worked